# I have query about about web.archive.org

Tags: api

I can see the that if call web.archive.org like this https://web.archive.org/web/*http://www.aiub.edu/* it returns some data.

I want to know, if it is possible to pass another parameter keyword to get only the links which contains that specific keywords. I have looked every, but I didn't find anything.

Though I am asking this, if I had missed something.

Thanks for you time.